# Regex - Capturing attributes from strings in varying order and presence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex in JavaScript which would match each of the lines below, and also capture the values of `image_path`, `caption` and `alt` as $1, $2 and $3 respectively.

```html
{{< shortcodes/responsive-image image_path="/image.jpg" caption="A caption" alt="Alt text" >}}

{{< shortcodes/responsive-image caption="A caption" alt="Alt text" image_path="/image.jpg" >}}

{{< shortcodes/responsive-image image_path="/image.jpg" alt="Alt text" >}}

{{< shortcodes/responsive-image image_path="/image.jpg" caption="A caption" >}}

{{< shortcodes/responsive-image image_path="/image.jpg" >}}

{{<   shortcodes/responsive-image   >}}
```

The following would be the captures that I'm trying to extract from the lines above:

```html
$1: "/image.jpg" $2: "A caption" $3: "Alt text"

$1: "/image.jpg" $2: "A caption" $3: "Alt text"

$1: "/image.jpg" $2: null $3: "Alt text"

$1: "/image.jpg" $2: "A caption" $3: null

$1: "/image.jpg" $2: null $3: null

$1: null $2: null $3: null
```

Comment: You could [capture in several lookaheads](https://regex101.com/r/MzdNRK/1) for being independent of order [like in this demo](https://tio.run/##pVHBboMwDL3zFVYuDWiF66SOVjvsK4BWWZYCVUqixEOVKN9ODdLaSlu3bjvEip/t957snWiFl662OG8fh0ErBI/OQwpZMOu6J/CVcSjNm/KJU96axtetmtd7USqY4sYKrFKWTEm8syUDKSzWpknZ88eXgdBIuUZAdUAGy76fPfyscAfTLRN3Ktwa/5vf32zkn5RX4/AtAUytxSIIxsvGW@NehKz49r2RoxFOaAhdADAen6bp9gTFe4HUlRB/7qMLf/5JIH/lqzRbL4tode2VZ2tWRCE7hufyeQtf1KZ9X/AkXJAjSTpGq1ibkpMsYT29YTgB). Please show your current attempt for knowing where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have Javascript tagged, I am going to assume you need a pattern that is JS compatible. I am also going to assume that each text is on a single line.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/b6zw76/1)

```
^(?=.*\bshortcodes\/responsive-image\b)(?=(?:.*image_path="([^"]+)")?)(?=(?:.*caption="([^"]+)")?)(?=(?:.*alt="([^"]+)")?)
```

**Quick Breakdown**

- ^ - Start at beginning of line
- (?=.*\bshortcodes/responsive-image\b) - Positive lookahead to find "shortcodes/responsive-image" on the line
- (?=(?:.*image_path="([^"]+)")?) - Positive lookahead to find image_path= on the line which is inside a non capture group that is optional and has a group to match what we want which will be Group $1
- The above will ensure the cursor is still at the start of the line since we have used Lookaheads so we can repeat the process for "caption=" and "alt="
- As we now have 3 consecutive groups in order while using the lookaheads to determine if the matching items are present while they are optional, Groups will be created for any matches

Please refer to the [Example](https://regex101.com/r/b6zw76/1) link for a more detailed explanation if required.

The exact output is quite difficult with JS, in terms of providing empty Groups.

So I am also including a PCRE(wont work in Javascript) version, incase you can use it. This pattern utilizes a [Branch Reset](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) and an empty Group so that if the param items don't match it will match the empty group with the |(or)

ie: `image_path="([^"]+)"|()` - if image_path="([^"]+)" does not match, match () empty Group creating the null/empty Group item, and that is repeated with the other match words similar to the previous example

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/b6zw76/2)

```
^(?=.*\bshortcodes\/responsive-image\b)(?=(?|.*image_path="([^"]+)"|()))(?=(?|.*caption="([^"]+)"|()))(?=(?|.*alt="([^"]+)"|()))
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly in terms of capturing the values of the 3 groups, with varying order and presence. Only thing is, when I use substustion, the full string is always appended. For examle `$1---$2---` returns `/image.jpg---A caption---{{< shortcodes/responsive-image image_path="/image.jpg" caption="A caption" alt="Alt text" >}}` for the first line. Can it be modified to return just the groups- ie `/image.jpg---A caption---`?

Comment: Hi AJP, glad to hear that. In terms of the substitution, if you wanted to clear out the entire string just add `.*$` to the end of the pattern. Since the cursor is still at the beginning of the line, this will select all the text on the line and replace it completely  with your substitution.